# javascript print nested array to screen

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data array, there are multiple objects in this array, and the data object is an array. There may be more than one object in this array. How can I copy these objects under a single array?

```js
const test = []
const data = [
    {
        "_id": "124141",
        "name": "test",
        "data": [
            {
                "price":10,
                "title": "sda"
            },
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2525",
        "name": "test2",
        "data": [
            {
                "price":20,
                "title": "asdas"
            },
            
        ]
        }
]
```

```js
[{
    "price":10,
    "title": "sda"
},
{
    "price":20,
    "title": "asdas"
},
]
```

If this is the output I expect, it should be like this. how can I do that

Comment: `data.map(e => e.data[0])` ??

Comment: @JohnnyMopp data array can have multiple objects

Comment: console.log(data.map((e,i) => test.push(e.data[i])))
console.log(test) I tried like this but I'm not sure if it's a healthy solution

Comment: `data.map(e => e.data).flat()` ??

Comment: TypeError: data.map(...).flat is not a function

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "_id": "124141",
        "name": "test",
        "data": [
            {
                "price":10,
                "title": "sda"
            },
            {
                "price":99,
                "title":"aaaaa"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2525",
        "name": "test2",
        "data": [
            {
                "price":20,
                "title": "asdas"
            },
            
        ]
        }
];
console.log(data.map(e => e.data).flat());
// OR
console.log(data.flatMap(e => e.data));
```

Comment: Thanks. const flattenedData = data.map(e => e.data).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
console.log(flattenedData); I tried this way and got a successful result.

Comment: Maybe you are using an old browser that doesn't support `flat`. [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#browser_compatibility)